# Прилагательное, начинающееся числом. Однородный ряд

Tags: числительные, прилагательные, однородные-члены, сложные-прилагательные, наращение

*Обычно там есть требование 3, 5, 10-летнего опыта работы.*

*Обычно там есть требование 3–5–10-летнего опыта работы.*

Как правильно оформить такой ряд?

Нашёл только правило про наращение числительных:

"Если подряд следуют более двух порядковых числительных, разделенных запятой, точкой с запятой или соединенных союзом, то падежное окончание наращивают только у последнего числительного: 1, 2 и 3-й вагоны, 70, 80, 90-е годы" (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Мильчина: 6.3.3.    Издания деловой и научной литератур
Рекомендуется словесно-цифровая форма, даже когда числа малы. Напр.: 1-, 2- и 3-секционные шкафы; 3- и 4-красочные машины.

Answer (score 6):

> Как правильно оформить такой ряд?

Правильно – с висячим дефисом:

***Обычно там есть требование 3-, 5-, 10-летнего опыта работы.***

Comment: Не могли бы подкрепить свой ответ ссылкой на правило?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что имеется в "Справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию" (Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. [**§ 43, п. 11**]):

> **Примечание 4.** Висячий дефис (см. § 42, п. 13) употребляется и при сложных прилагательных, например: ***семнадцати-** и восемнадцатилетние юноши и девушки; **кукурузно-, картофеле-, льно-, хлопко-** и силосоуборочные комбайны.*

А каковы же разъяснения? Смотрим **§ 42, п. 13**:

> При сочетании с помощью союза **и** двух или нескольких сложных существительных с одинаковой второй частью эта часть может приводиться только при последнем слове, а при предшествующих словах вместо нее пишется так называемый висячий дефис. Например: ***газо-** и электросварка* (ср. газосварка и электросварка); ***водо-** и газоснабжение; **радио-** и телепередачи; **авто-, мото-** и велогонки* (но при отсутствии союза **и** – слитное написание...).

Итак, союз **и** в однородном ряду отсутствует.

• Тогда правильно писать **слитно**:
*Обычно там есть требование **трехлетнего, пятилетнего, десятилетнего** опыта работы.*

•• Или с **обычным дефисом** (не висячим):
*Обычно там есть требование **3-летнего, 5-летнего, 10-летнего** опыта работы.*

••• Чтобы оформить однородные члены с помощью **висячего дефиса**, нужно обязательно в предложение **добавить** союз **и**:
*Обычно там есть требование **3-, 5- и 10-летнего** опыта работы.*

[IX. ПРАВОПИСАНИЕ СЛОЖНЫХ СЛОВ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm)
[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

Comment: Браво, Римма Михайловна!
Добавить нечего... :)