# Можно ли использовать «висячий дефис» в сочетаниях с союзом «или»?

Tags: орфография, однородные-члены, дефис

Натолкнуло меня открыть эту тему обсуждение вопроса
[***Прилагательное, начинающееся числом. Однородный ряд***](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443434/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4).

Однозначно правильным в соответствии с правилами, приведёнными в справочниках Розенталя, считается использование висячего дефиса при сочетании нескольких сложных существительных или прилагательных с одинаковой второй частью, если последний член этого сочетания присоединён к остальным союзом ***и***.

Пример:

> *Обычно там есть требование 3-, 5- **и** 10-летнего опыта работы.*

А какое написание следует считать возможным при использовании перед последним членом сочетания не союза ***и***, а союза ***или***?

Будет ли считаться неправильным использование висячего дефиса в таком, к примеру, предложении:

> *Обычно там есть требование 3-, 5- **или** 10-летнего опыта работы*.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот вопрос интересен противоречиями в правилах: Розенталь говорит, что висячий дефис можно использовать только при наличии союза **и**, Лопатин же такого условия не ставит.
Смотрим внимательно в ПАС:

> **§ 112.** Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют «висячим», напр.: *шарико- **и** роликоподшипники; лит- **и** изокружки; кино-, теле- **и** видеофильмы; не двух-, **а** трёхэтажный дом; **не только** англо- **и** франко-, **но и** русскоязычные тексты; **как** водо-, **так и** газоснабжение; до- **или** послеперестроечные процессы; **либо** теле-, **либо** радиопередача; обер- **и** унтер-офицеры.* Как видно из примеров, употребление висячего дефиса не зависит от слитного или дефисного написания сложных слов. [выделено  мной. — Р. М.]

• По Розенталю пишем так (с обычным дефисом):
*Обычно там есть требование **3-летнего, 5-летнего или 10-летнего** опыта работы.*

•• По Лопатину так (с висячим дефисом):
*Обычно там есть требование **3-, 5- или 10-летнего** опыта работы.*

■ Конечно, Розенталь — это наше всё, но *лопатинское* правило универсальнее.
Мне оно ближе — так что предложение с "или" пишем с висячим дефисом.

Нашлась **интереснейшая** статья. Вот из нее примеры предложений:

> На этот счет тебе придется проконсультироваться у своих друзей, исповедующих про-, **и** до-, **и** нео-, **и** антифрейдистские взгляды (Р. Облонская);
> Она была милой девочкой, к которой тянулось мое семи-, восьми-, в тот момент девяти-,  **а** позже еще и десятилетнее сердце (Н. Андреев);
> Всякая революция бого- **или** хотя бы религиеборческая (Л. Игошева).

[Дефис](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59#pp59)
[Висячий дефис и его употребление в современной речи](https://www.riash.ru/jour/article/view/234/234) (Н. А. Николина)

Comment: Римма, одно замечание. Розенталь ведь не говорит, что "висячий дефис можно использовать **только** при наличии союза ***и***".   Там написано: "При сочетании с помощью союза ***и*** двух или нескольких сложных существительных с одинаковой второй частью эта часть может приводиться **только** при последнем слове..."  То есть у него просто не говорится о других союзах.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: «_[у Розенталя] **просто не говорится** о других союзах_». === Да, не говорится. Особенно в конце примечания, где сказано так: «_но при отсутствии союза **И** – слитное написание_…»